# Running a standard java app in the JVM Runtime Container in Cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I want to run a 'normal' java application (with a main method) with the [JVM Runtime Container](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container).

1)
Is that possible in the free version? Currently (it seems) that I can only select 'JVM Web Application' (for war files)...

2) If so where or how can i select the JVM Runtime Container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you mean by a "normal" java application. If you mean that you'd like to launch the app via a Java main() method, the documentation page that you linked to is about running apps launched via a Java main() method, not a WAR file.

The following command from that doc is showing how to run an app packaged as a JAR and specifies its main class name.

`bees app:deploy -t java -R class=your.main.Class -R java_version=1.7 PATH_TO_APP_PACKAGE`

Comment: With normal i ment a Standard java app with a Main method and not a webapp. However with the free Version i am only able to upload war files - so how can i upload jars?

Comment: So it seems that the functionality to run java apps via main method is not available in the free version?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if someone is still looking for answer...

1. Make your java application (not the web application) as a jar file.
2. Upload the .jar file into cloudbees through "Bees Console" (that comes when you download cloudbees SDK). 
   Command to upload jar file is `bees app:deploy -a <app_name_in_cloudbees> -t Java <jar_file_locaiton_in_your_local_file_system> -Rclass=<fully_qualified_java_class_name_that_contains_method>`
   ex: `bees app:deploy -a helloworld -t Java C:\projects\helloworld.jar -Rclass=Helloworld`
   This will upload and deploy your jar file to cloudbees.
3. Go to log tab to see your console output.
4. Now, in beta version of cloudbees, we can upload jar files hence forth to update our jar file contents.

Reference: http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container

Comment: Thanks. I stopped my efforts back than since nobody seems to know. But with your description i might try again...

Comment: I found few more references for more details:
Youtube Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scSFa2Kec4c
Cloudbees Ref.: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK